# Random word combinations javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using https://github.com/Atrox/haikunatorjs/issues/38 to generate random word combos like heroku. I plan to use them as memorable IDs. BUT...

As you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/8kxj9pq7pl everytime the app restarts the random combos are generated in the same order.

How can i modify the script to get the combinations *in random order*?

```
    const Haikunator = require("haikunator");
```

Comment: Randomize the seed.

Comment: Remove the `seed` property. That will do the trick. Use it only when you want to generate the same sequence again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're creating the `Haikunator`, define the seed as `seed: new Date().getTime()`. That way, the seed for the random generator will change every time you load the page.

Comment: This question/answer is only helpful if the OP's links stay intact, you should include the incorrect code / code OP had on line 54 in your answer too, to help future readers if the links go bonkers.

Comment: Removing the seed looks like ti works... Or giving it a random number... Thanks